# Deploying multi-dependency .NET Winforms app via cloud/virtualised environments

Tags: .net, winforms, cloud, virtualization

We have developed a .NET Winforms app that connects to a central SQL Server database via webservices. The thick client itself relies on a number a external dependencies such as Microsoft Office, Office Web Components and .NET Framework 4.0.

What are the options available to deploy such an application (just the .NET Winforms thick client part) like a virtualized app? The things we are trying to achieve are:

- Simplify installation process, users currently have to install a number of prerequisites each with its own idiosyncrasies in various Windows environments.
- Homogenize the user experience and reduce support costs. Additionally, allow the app to be run on platforms other than Windows.

The scale we are looking at is approximately 10,000 desktop users.

I have looked at the Cloud Paging offering from Numecent http://www.numecent.com/technology/cloudpaging.html and it is similar to what is required. Want to know if anyone has had experiences with transferring a traditional .NET Winform apps to a virtualized offering and if anyone has any suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

Numecent addresses delivery of your .NET application and allows integration of external dependencies of other software assets including (and not limited to) Microsoft Office, Office Web Components, and the .Net 4.0 Framework at the thick client.  Also, any or all of those dependencies can be included as part of your package (if they are not on or don't wish to use those assets the thick client).

For delivery, Cloudpaging will substantially reduce the size of those applications and its dependencies.  For example, a very popular CAD application was delivered fully functioning with .NET in 134MB (the CAD application itself was 3GB!).  I suspect an SQL thick client would be much smaller.

As far as your other questions, simplification of the installation process and dealing with prerequisites on different Windows environments are fundamental to reducing support costs as well as better satisfying end users.  Numecent has demonstrated both and has successful commercial deployments in production, similar to your usecase.  They also have solutions for other platforms (e.g. tablet).

I suggest you go to

http://www.numecent.com/contact/contact-us.html

and someone will contact you with a detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, it somewhat answers my questions. However looking for alternative options and any experience with alternatives so I can contrast ans compare.